# Inner static class inherits inner static class, and the outer class of the child also inherits the outer class of the parent, why I can't do casting

Tags: java

I have the following classes:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Tree<E> {
    BinarySearchTreeNode<E> root = null;
    protected int size = 0;
    private LinkedList<E> inOrderData = new LinkedList<>();
    private LinkedList<E> postOrderData = new LinkedList<>();
    private LinkedList<E> preOrderData = new LinkedList<>();

    public BinarySearchTree() {

    }

    public BinarySearchTree(E[] objects) {
        for (E e : objects) {
            insert(e);
        }
    }

    public static class BinarySearchTreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
        protected E data;
        protected BinarySearchTreeNode<E> left;
        protected BinarySearchTreeNode<E> right;

        public BinarySearchTreeNode(E e) {
            data = e;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.data.toString();
        }
    }

public LinkedList<BinarySearchTreeNode<E>> path(E e) {
    LinkedList<BinarySearchTreeNode<E>> list = new LinkedList<>();
    BinarySearchTreeNode<E> current = root;
    while (current != null) {
        list.add(current);
        int compareElement = e.compareTo(current.data);
        if (compareElement < 0) {
            current = current.left;
        } else if (compareElement > 0) {
            current = current.right;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

and

```
public class AVLTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BinarySearchTree<E> {
    public AVLTree() {

    }

    public AVLTree(E[] objects) {
        super(objects);
    }

    protected static class AVLTreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BinarySearchTree.BinarySearchTreeNode<E> {
        protected int hight = 0;

        public AVLTreeNode(E data) {
            super(data);
        }
    }
    private void balance(E e) {
        LinkedList<BinarySearchTreeNode<E>> path = path(e);
        for (int i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            AVLTreeNode<E> A = (AVLTreeNode<E>) path.get(i);
            updateHeight(A);
            AVLTreeNode<E> parentOfA = (A == root) ? null : (AVLTreeNode<E>) (path.get(i - 1));

            switch (balanceFactor(A)) {
                case -2:
                    if (balanceFactor((AVLTreeNode<E>) A.left) <= 0) {
                        LLRotate(A, parentOfA);
                    } else {
                        LRRotate(A, parentOfA);
                    }
                case +2:
                    if (balanceFactor((AVLTreeNode<E>) A.right) >= 0) {
                        RRRotate(A, parentOfA);
                    } else {
                        RLRotate(A, parentOfA);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But at the runtime, I get the following exception on the following line:

`AVLTreeNode<E> A = (AVLTreeNode<E>) path.get(i);`

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6\lib\idea_rt.jar=61223:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.3.1\junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.0.0\apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.3.1\junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.3.1\junit-platform-commons-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.1.1\opentest4j-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.3.1\junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.3.1\junit-jupiter-api-5.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\junit\vintage\junit-vintage-engine\5.3.1\junit-vintage-engine-5.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Albaraa Kefaya\PhotonE\DataStructuresProjects\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6\lib\junit.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 datastructures.tests.TestAVLTree

java.lang.ClassCastException: class datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.BinarySearchTree$BinarySearchTreeNode cannot be cast to class datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.AVLTree$AVLTreeNode (datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.BinarySearchTree$BinarySearchTreeNode and datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.AVLTree$AVLTreeNode are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

at datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.AVLTree.balance(AVLTree.java:32)
at datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.AVLTree.insert(AVLTree.java:26)
at datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.BinarySearchTree.<init>(BinarySearchTree.java:20)
at datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.AVLTree.<init>(AVLTree.java:12)
at datastructures.tests.TestAVLTree.<init>(TestAVLTree.java:10)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:431)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassTestDescriptor.java:342)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:289)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:281)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:269)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:66)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

*Process finished with exit code -1*

I can't figure out why I can't downcast `BinarySearchTreeNode<E>` to `AVLTreeNode<E>`

Comment: To get proper answer easier it could be better to provide [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)). In other words *minimal* example (without any unnecessary parts like asking user for input if we can provide it already in code, like data for arrays and such) but still *complete* example which we could copy-paste to our machines and run without modifications to *reproduce* exactly same problem you are getting.

Comment: You haven’t shown your `insert` method, but I’m guessing it always adds `BinarySearchTreeNode` objects to your tree.  You cannot change an object’s class just by casting it.  When the object is created, its class, and the classes it inherits, are fixed and can never change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace Shows that the `AVLTree` child constructor in calling the `BinarySearchTree` super constructor which again calls an `insert`, overriden in the child.

```
at datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.AVLTree.balance(AVLTree.java:32)
at datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.AVLTree.insert(AVLTree.java:26)
at datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.BinarySearchTree.<init>(BinarySearchTree.java:20)
at datastructures.trees.BinaryTrees.AVLTree.<init>(AVLTree.java:12)
at datastructures.tests.TestAVLTree.<init>(TestAVLTree.java:10)
```

Many an IDE will warn about the call to the overridable `insert` in the constructor.

What happens is quite dirty:

```
class A {
    A() {
        f();
    }
    protected void f() {
    }
}

class B {
    String s;
    String t = null;
    String u = "U";
    B() {
        // 0. B is not created, all fields are defaulted: 0, null, false, 0.0.
        //    s == null, t == null, u == null (!)
        // 1. super() is called
        //    s == "S",  t == "T",  u == null (!)
        // 2. all field initialisations are done: for t and u.
        //    s == "S",  t == null, u == "U" 
        // 3. the rest of the constructor code is done.
        System.out.printf("B.B: s %s; t %s; u %s%n", s, t, u);
    }

    @Override
    protected void f() {
        System.out.printf("B.f: s %s; t %s; u %s%n", s, t, u);
        // When called from A(): s, t and u (!) are null.
        s = "S";
        t = "T";
    }
}
```

- `f` does not receive initialized values; deadly in case of `new ArrayList<>()` and such.
- `f`'s assignments will be overwritten by field initialisations.

Hence **do not use overridable Methods in constructors**.

In your case the `AVLTree.insert` may not use initialized fields of `AVLTree`.

One way to solve this would be a factory method:

```
class AVLTree {
    AVLTree() { … not calling insert … }

    /** Factory method. */
    public static AVLTree create(E.. data) {
        AVLTree tree = new AVLTree();
        tree.insert(…);
    }
```

---

***The error*** that the private inner parent node class is created by the super class method's and the private inner child node class only in the child class, can be resolved in the same manner:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<…> … {

     protected static class Node { … }

     protected BinarySearchTree.Node createNode() { return new Node(); }
}

public class AVLTree<…> … {
     protected static class Node extends BinarySearchTree.Node { … }

     @Override
     protected AVLTree.Node createNode() { return new AVLTree.Node(); }
}
```

Do not use an explicit new Node in the base class.